# How to get a string as it is from a json column in hive

Tags: json, hive, special-characters

The query is like this

```
select get_json_object(xkey,'$.note') from db_name.table_name where id=638112577;
```

The value of key 'note' in the JSON is

```
{....,"note": "\\u2604\\ufe0freality stone \\n\\n\\u2604\\ufe0freality stone \\n\\n \\u2604\\ufe0freality stone",....}
```

When i'm using get_json_object() it gives the below content

```
(':comet:reality stone ',)
('',)
(':comet:reality stone ',)
('',)
(' :comet:reality stone',)
```

So, is it possible to get the string value for respective key as it is from the source json.

Comment: please add create table and full json example if is possible.

Comment: I wish i could. But that's not possible. It's just a normal EXTERNAL table.

Comment: what about the table creation? it would be useful know what serde u r using ..